# Player not moving in pygame; no error messages

Tags: python, pygame

I created this program and when I run it the player is not moving. I checked and everything is right. Just in case you need it I am using python 3.8.6. Can you please help me? Here is my code.

```
# Game Loop
running = True

while running:
    screen.fill((128, 20, 128))

for event in pygame.event.get():

    player(playerX, playerY)
    pygame.display.update()

        # Movment
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pygame.K_a:
        player_x_change -= 10
    if event.key == pygame.K_d:
        player_x_change += 10
    if event.key == pygame.K_w:
            player_y_change -= 10
    if event.key == pygame.K_s:
            player_y_change += 10

if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
    if event.key == pygame.K_a:
        player_x_change = 0
    if event.key == pygame.K_d:
        player_x_change = 0

      playerX += player_x_change
      playerY += player_y_change
        
    # Close the game
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem now, if anyone wants the code here it is. :) It turns out I put the "close program" code too early and it doesn't work until the close button is pressed. So my player did move, but only for a second.

```
# Game Loop
running = True
while running:

    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = False

    # if keystroke is pressed check whether its right or left
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            playerX_change = -5
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            playerX_change = 5

    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            playerX_change = 0

playerX += playerX_change
if playerX <= 0:
    playerX = 0
elif playerX >= 736:
    playerX = 736
```

Answer (score 1):

It's probably just an indentation error (perhaps pasting to the question), but none of your events are being handled because of the `if event.type` clauses are not inside the `for event` loop.

Simply fixing this indentation alleviates this.

The next problem is that you calculate the `player_x_change` and `player_y_change`, but never apply the amounts to `playerX` and `playerY`.

Since these changes only happen when `pygame.KEYDOWN` is received, it's easy to simply add this inside the event handler:

```
    # Movment
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_a:
            player_x_change -= 10
        elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
            player_x_change += 10
        elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
            player_y_change -= 10
        elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
            player_y_change += 10
        # Move the player
        playerX += player_x_change
        playerY += player_y_change
```

Note the use of `if .. elif`.  If the event is one particular type, it cannot possibly be another type too (at the same time).  This means it's not necessary to keep re-checking the type.  Using `elif` ("else if") helps with these checks, by stopping the check once a match is found.  It is more efficient.

Final code:

```
import pygame

# Window size
WINDOW_WIDTH    = 400
WINDOW_HEIGHT   = 400
WINDOW_SURFACE  = pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF
BACKGROUND = (128,  20, 128)


### initialisation
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.display.set_caption("Not Moving")

# Game Loop
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True

while running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # Close the game
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        # Movment
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                player_x_change -= 10
            elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                player_x_change += 10
            elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
                player_y_change -= 10
            elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                player_y_change += 10
            # Move the player
            playerX += player_x_change
            playerY += player_y_change

        # DON'T REALLY NEED THIS
        #elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        #    if event.key == pygame.K_a:
        #        player_x_change = 0
        #    elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
        #        player_x_change = 0

    # Re-draw the screen
    screen.fill( BACKGROUND )
    player(playerX, playerY)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)                # limit the re-fresh rate to save electricity

pygame.quit()
```

I also added a frame-rate limiter with a `pygame.time.Clock()` object, just to save some CPU.

Comment: I don't have the best CPU in the world, but I am looking for  something like in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FfWpgLFMI7w&t=599s

Comment: Also, even with your solution, my program doesn't work. Can you look into the version compatibility?

Comment: @DARSIN - "doesn't work" how?  Something like: Nothing happens?  crashes? blank screen? too slow? too fast? etc.  What does happen?

Comment: It just shows errors in my Visual Studio Code Terminal and when I fix them, it still doesn't work. Any chance this is a text editor problem?